# Select element show up in the next 2 month. SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

This is a result of a SELECT query of mine.

```
Code    Name         MONTH
------- ------------ -----------
Cust3   CustName3    1
Cust2   CustName2    2
Cust5   CustName5    3
Cust2   CustName2    5
Cust2   CustName2    6
Cust3   CustName3    7
Cust6   CustName6    8
Cust1   CustName1    10
Cust1   CustName1    11
Cust3   CustName3    12
```

Now I want to select rows that have the same `Code` value for two consecutive months, for example `Cust2` is contiguous in months 5 and 6 and `Cust1` is contiguous in months 10 and 11:

```
Code    Name         MONTH
------- ------------ -----------
Cust2   CustName2    5
Cust2   CustName2    6
Cust1   CustName1    10
Cust1   CustName1    11
```

Comment: This sounds like a gaps and islands problem. There's a huge number of blog posts and other material available. You probably should take a look at them.

Comment: The answer of @wewesthemenace is  working for me.

Comment: @Dung Ho please mark an answer as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach using `ROW_NUMBER` and `COUNT() OVER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4db5/2/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = [Month] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY [Month])
    FROM TestData
),
Cte2 AS(
    SELECT *,
        CC = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Code, RN)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    Code, Name, [Month]
FROM Cte2
WHERE CC >= 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume the underlying table is denormalized and has this schema:

```
Code varchar(n),
Name nvarchar(n),
Month int
```

...and that there is only 1 row for each month.

We can use [the `LAG` function in T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to compare neighbour rows. We don't need the optional `OVER` partition-by clause as it's a single data set group:

```
SELECT
    [Code],
    [Month]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Code],
        LAG( [Code], 1 ) AS LastCode
        [Month],
        LAG( [Month], 1 ) AS LastMonth
   FROM
       [sourceTable]
   ORDER BY
       [Month] ASC
) AS Lagged
WHERE
    Lagged.[Code] = Lagged.LastCode
    AND 
    Lagged.[Month] = Lagged.LastMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

The above two answers are pretty neat. Here's another alternative way of solving this ([example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27937/5)), perhaps not as elegantly:

```
select * from
(
  -- join to itself, but for month - join to previous month
  select a.code, a.month
  from test a
  inner join test b on a.code=b.code and a.month = b.month-1

  union all

  -- join to itself, but for month - join to next month
  select a.code, a.month
  from test a
  inner join test b on a.code=b.code and a.month = b.month+1
) a
order by a.code, a.month
```